# Why do write() syscall fails with ENOSPC?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems, system-calls, ext4

As per my understanding, write() syscall write data from uspace buffer to kspace buffer, not to the disk (or disk driver), provided O_SYNC, O_DIRECT flags are not used in open(). To test it I have created one 100MB ext4 File System, fill it to 100% using below dd command:

```
# mount -t ext4
/mnt1 type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel)

# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt1/dd_infinite.txt bs=1k
dd: error writing '/mnt1/dd_infinite.txt': No space left on device
91455+0 records in
91454+0 records out
93648896 bytes (94 MB, 89 MiB) copied, 0.871788 s, 107 MB/s

# df -h
Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
93M   91M     0 100% /mnt1
```

Then I used below code to create one file and write some data into it. I was expecting fsync() to give me ENOSPC, but no it was the write() syscall which was giving me ENOSPC. My question is why? How does write() know that there is no space left on device when its task is just to copy data from uspace to kspace?

Does linux kernel by default allocate data blocks during write() but flush data into it later? Or there is something which I am missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(
        int             argc,
        char            *argv[])
{
        int             fd, rv;
        char            buf[80] = { 0 };
        memset(buf, 'A', 80);
        fd = open("/mnt1/hello.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
        if (fd == -1) {
                perror("open");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        rv = write(fd, buf, 80);
        if (rv == -1) {
                perror("write");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        rv = fsync(fd);
        if (rv == -1) {
                perror("fsync");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        rv = close(fd);
        if (rv == -1) {
                perror("close");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output:

```
# gcc enospc_file_create.c -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
# ./a.out
write: No space left on device
#
```

OS details:

```
(RHEL 8.4) Linux 4.18.0-305.el8.x86_64
```

Comment: "As per my understanding, write() syscall write data from uspace buffer to kspace buffer, not to the disk" - Now, your understanding is wrong. System call `write` **effectively** writes the data to the **disk**. It could be a complete disk modification, or partial one: it depends on the driver. But in any case the `write` checks the space on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, write() syscall write data from uspace buffer to kspace buffer, not to the disk (or disk driver)

Technically, it depends on the driver, but you're right *for the most part* for file systems: the actual write to disk is buffered in the page cache. Eventually, the page cache is flushed to disk either manually (eg. by fsync(2)), or automatically by kernel heuristics.

That being said, many applications do not call fsync(2) at all. So, if the lack of space on the device was only detected on writeback, then data could be lost. This is not good. So, most file systems [citation needed] will check whether there is enough space on device while handling write(2).

> How does write() know that there is no space left on device when its task is just to copy data from uspace to kspace?

The file system has a block allocator that manages how much block storage is available, and where those blocks are. While handling the write(2), the file system checks whether there are enough free blocks on disk to handle the data that will eventually be written.

Aside: On Linux, fsync(2) can return ENOSPC, but on some operating systems fsync(2) cannot return ENOSPC. For example, [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fsync&sektion=2).